# Are std::stack::push and std::stack:pop thread safe?

Tags: c++, stl, thread-safety

**Do I need to guard my `push()` and `pop()` calls with a mutex, or are they internally  thread safe?**

The code I wish to write looks like this

```
parallel for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    ...
    s.push(...);
    ...
}
```

I am not sure where to look about the thread safety of the STL containers I am using. I checked [this reference](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stack.html), but it does not mention anything about thread safety.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not internally thread safe. Write operations to containers and container adapters from more than one thread are not required by the standard to be safe in this respect, so you have to apply some synchronisation mechanism.

Answer (score 3):

The only thread-safety guarantees you can hope for from the standard library is that you can read them from different threads, and you can modify *different instances* from different threads (ie: no non-thread-safe global state).

Any attempt to modify the same object from different threads will end in tears.